# RPG: store dialog in DB or JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm creating a RPG. I was originally storing NPC dialog in a JS object. I could cycle through lengthy dialog in an array as I wanted. I can also store objects with K:V pairs.

That being said, is it **easier/faster** to manage, store and retrieve dialog in JSON/JS Object on the front end:

```
var dialog = {
    quests : {
        quest1 : {  
            NPCName: {      
                "Task 1 - Introductions" :
                {
                    "dialog" :
                    [
                        "I'm Pedro",
                        "Welcome to my neighborhood",
                         etc...,
                    ],
                    "wordBank" :
                    {
                        "Hola" : "Hello",
                        "Como" : "What",         
                    }
```

Or in a database, where you retrieve through AJAX requests and parse as JSON like so?

[image]

```
        function getData (functionToRun) {  
            $.getJSON("phpscripts.php", {"_functionToRun" : functionToRun},
                function (returned_data) {                      
                    var nm = returned_data.task_name,
                        spn = returned_data.task_spanish,
                        rsp = returned_data.task_userResponse;

                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Easier/faster compared to what?

Comment: @cmbasnett compared to a database. Read the question.

Comment: Why not both? Key/value store + JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to do what you're doing in the first code snippet but load that data via JSON rather than embedding it in the page. Sending a JSON request for every individual piece of dialog gets expensive with loading time and it's unnecessary traffic. I'd recommend loading an entire quest's dialogs per JSON request to the server.

Comment: Why is it better to store as JSON than embedding it in the page/loading it

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that ALL of the dialogs aren't needed immediately, so for the sake of initial page loading time, it would be better if only the dialogs for the first quest (or whichever quest the user is in) are loaded and then loading the next as its needed. By loading a whole quest at a time, there's less transactions with the server and also, there isn't any need to load completed quests again. If you have a ton of users playing your game, unnecessary bandwidth usage can really add up.